# Copy folder from Dockerfile to CI-Host machine during building of the Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I build an Image with a Dockerfile in Jenkins.
In the Dockerfile `./gradlew build` is run which generates .xml-files for the JUnit Test-results.

I want to copy these files into the Jenkins which ran `docker build` so that the Jenkins UI can display the results.

How would I do that?

There are no containers yet so `docker cp` or volumes are not options afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container without starting it, then you can copy from it:

```sh
docker create --name tmp_container ci_image
docker cp tmp_container:/source ./destination
docker rm tmp_container
```

Documentation: [docker create](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/).

Comment: That works when no test fails.
When tests fail, then the docker build crashes and there is no image to create a container from.

Comment: Well, you should probably reconsider your global CI workflow: building an image that runs tests during its build does not seem to be a good idea in my opinion, because of the issue you just mentionned, and also because of test files stored in the image filesystem. What I usually do is to build the image, then start a container to run test/quality tools, then stop the container when the pipeline ended. I can edit my answer with an example Jenkinsfile if you want.

Comment: We want to run the build and testing in a Dockerfile for caching.
Before we had caching we just ran the tests directly from Jenkins.

Comment: What do you need to cache ? There must be a better way, I don't see any advantage to run tests during image builds.

Comment: actually your solution brought us to the solution so I will mark it as solved. Thank you